# Наследование классов и методов

Tags: ооп, jquery, javascript

Хочу разобраться уже раз и навсегда, что и как, а именно с наследниками классов и методами? Допустим, есть класс `example`

```
function example(){
    this.init = function(name){
     this.name = name;
    }
    this.sayName = function(){
         alert(this.name);
    }
}

var ex = new example();
    ex.init("Andy");
    ex.sayName();
```

Тут все очевидно, никаких премудростей нету, создается объект класса `example`, при вызове метода `init` устанавливается имя объекта, при вызове `sayName` выводится имя Alert'ом.

Как создать *потомок* (экземпляр, наследник, даже как и выразить правильно затрудняюсь описать) класса `example`, и переопределить метод `sayName`, пускай он теперь ни Alert'ом выводит имя, а в *консоль* записывает?

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = function(name){
  this.name = name;
  this.log = function(){
    alert(this.name);
  }
}

var o1 = new obj('test'),
    o2 = new obj('toster');
o2.log();
o2.log = function(){
  console.log(this.name);
}
o1.log();
o2.log();
```

Можете ещё почитать [тут](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/ru-javascript-the-core/).